# Can .net mvc routing cause JavaScript errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am having a lot of trouble using routing infrastructure of asp.net mvc2. I have following routes registered in my global.asax file

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "strict",
              "{controller}.mvc/{docid}/{action}/{id}",
              new { action = "Index", id = "", docid = "" },
              new { docid = @"\d+"}

            );
 routes.MapRoute(
              "default",
              "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
              new { action = "Index", id = "" },
              new { docConstraint = new DocumentConstraint() }
            );
```

The problem is with first route ("strict"). Three kind of urls can match first route. mycontroller/23/myaction, mycontroller/23/myaction/12 or mycontroller/23/mvaction/stringid. If I try to use this route without specifying value of id everything works fine for example:

```
Html.ActionLink("Link text", "ActionName", new{docid = 23});
```

Everything goes well, but if I use links like:

```
  Html.ActionLink("Link text", "ActionName", new{docid = 23, id = 223})
```

This will produce url currentcontroller.mvc/23/ActionName/223 that is absolutely correct but when it loads the page it gives a JavaScript error in jquery1.4.2.min.js file.

This is strange: if I change id to someid =223 it will reflect in query string and there will be no JS error.

Edit: I have done some further debugging and found when both id and docid are mentioned in route values one thing is ignored in global.asax that is the ignore path.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

routes.ignoreRoute is totally bypassed and I can see names of JS files in route value dictionary while debugging in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we drag scripts from solution explorer to site.master it results in following output

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="../../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The leading dots (..) are creating the problem. Putting source path in `url.content` or using /scripts instead of `../../scripts` will solve the problem because these leading periods are forcing them to match some route in global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

> it gives javascript error in
>   jquery1.4.2.min.js file

The most likely cause for this is that something you are displaying on the page is different and you are performing an action that is causing the error. Can you supply enough of a sample from the rendered page to show what you are using jQuery for?

Comment: Problem may not be related to javascript. as i mentioned in my question as i use id parameter along with the docid parameter the error occurred. if i change id to someid(or whatever) everything works fine. I think (i may be wrong) problem occured when  "{controller}.mvc/{docid}/{action}/{id}" is matched

Comment: i have done some debugging and updated the question plz c if u can help me here regards